# android mapping APIs

Tags: android, api, maps

I am making an android mapping app and I know more about APIs ,but i need to know if someone can help me in finding an API that is enable me to change the server of the map to a local one. 
   I need also some tutorial on that API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

- MapsForge - Both, API adn documentation in the link: [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/)
- Osmdroid - Both, API adn documentation in the link: [Osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

mapsforge. Both, API adn documentation in the link: [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/)